# How can I alphabetize a set of text nodes, set anchor tags, and have them reference each other?

Tags: html, xml, sorting, xslt, grouping

I am attempting to alphabetize a set of text nodes in an XSLT sheet. The text nodes come from parent elements that have two separate attribute tags that I need to account for. They also need to carry an anchor tag for navigation, which I have solved for using a key. Here's an example of the XML:

```
<collection>
    <record>
        <datafield tag='1'>
            <subfield>Apple</subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag='2'>
            <subfield>Red Fruit</subfield>
        </datafield>
    </record>
    <record>
        <datafield tag='1'>
            <subfield>Cheese</subfield>
        </datafield>
    </record>
    <record>
        <datafield tag='1'>
            <subfield>Potato</subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag='2'>
            <subfield>Idaho Gold</subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag='2'>
            <subfield>Spud</subfield>
        </datafield>
    </record>
</collection>
```

I am attempting to create a thesaurus that lists preferred terms and the non-desired terms together, where the non-desired terms point to the preferred terms.

The desired output is:

```
<HTML>
    
    <body>
        <div name="navigation"> 
            <p><a href="#a"> <a href="#b"> <a href="#c"> <!-- etc. --></p>
        </div>
        
        <div name="content">

        <p><a name="a"></a><strong>Apple</strong></p>
        <p style="padding-left:15px;"><a name="a"></a>Use for Red Fruit</p>

        <p><a name="c"></a><strong>Cheese</strong></p>

        <p><a name="i"></a>Idaho Gold</p>
        <p style="padding-left:15px;">USE <strong>Potato</strong></p>   

        <p><a name="p"></a><strong>Potato</strong></p>
        <p style="padding-left:15px;"><a name="p"></a>Use for Idaho Gold</p>
        <p style="padding-left:15px;"><a name="p"></a>Use for Spud</p>
        
        <p><a name="r"></a>Red Fruit</p>
        <p style="padding-left:15px;">USE <strong>Apple</strong></p>

        <p><a name="s"></a>Spud</p>
        <p style="padding-left:15px;">USE <strong>Potato</strong></p>


        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The thesaurus will ideally be alphabetized and both preferred and non-preferred terms will be mixed together. As hopefully I have been able to illustrate, my challenge is getting @tag='2' to appear twice in the list. Once by itself to point to the preferred term and then again underneath it's associated preferred term. Here is an example of the XSLT I currently have:

```
<xsl: stylesheet> 

    <xsl:key name="letter" match="//record/datafield[@tag='1']/subfield" use="substring(.,1,1)" />

    <xsl:template match="collection">
        <xsl:variable name="main-doc" select="."/>
        <HTML>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
                
                <div name="navigation">
                    <p>
                        <xsl:for-each select="'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'">
                            <a href="#{.}"> 
                                <xsl:if test="not( key('letter',.,$main-doc))">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="title">I go nowhere</xsl:attribute>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                |
                            </a>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </p>
                    
                </div>
                <div name="content">              
                    <xsl:call-template name="terms"/>
                    <xsl:call-template name="notPreferred"/>           
                </div>
            </body>
        </HTML>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="terms">
        
        <xsl:for-each select="//record">
            
            <xsl:sort select="datafield[@tag='1']/subfield/text()"/> 
            <p><strong>
                <xsl:value-of select="datafield[@tag='1']/subfield"/>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="datafield[@tag='1']/subfield" group-by="substring(.,1,1)">
                    <a name="{current-grouping-key()}"></a>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </strong></p>
        
        
        <xsl:for-each select="datafield[@tag='2']">
            <p class="style="padding-left:15px;">Use for <xsl:value-of select="subfield"/></p>
        </xsl:for-each>
            
        </xsl:for-each>
        
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="notPreferred">
    
    <xsl:for-each select="//record/datafield[@tag='2']">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="subfield/text()"/></p>
        <p class=".indent">USE <strong><xsl:value-of select="../datafield[@tag='1']/subfield"/></strong></p>
        
    </xsl:for-each>
    
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This currently produces two seperate lists one for @tag=1 and one for @tag=2 in addition to showing the not-preferred term under the preferred term. I would like to incorporate @tag=2 into the alphabetical listing that @tag=1 has. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The required logic is not entirely clear. Try perhaps something along the lines of:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/collection">
    <result>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="record/datafield" group-by="substring(subfield, 1, 1)">
            <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" />
            <group name="{current-grouping-key()}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="datafield[@tag='1']">
    <term>
        <xsl:value-of select="subfield"/>
    </term>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="../datafield[@tag='2']" mode="associated"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="datafield[@tag='2']">
    <term>
        <xsl:value-of select="subfield"/>
    </term>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="../datafield[@tag='1']" mode="associated"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="datafield" mode="associated">
    <associated-term>
        <xsl:value-of select="subfield"/>
    </associated-term>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you! This did it for me. The only thing I had to account for was the navigation portion of my above code used only the first letter while the tag grouping needed to look at the first five letters to properly alphabetize the full list of terms I was using. I believe I found an adequate solution though.